# Nokogiri parsing HTML

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse my HTML code. My HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Important Preferences</p>
      To see as much as possible
      <br />Relaxation
      <br />Quality of accommodation
      <br />Quality of activities
      <br />Independence & flexibility
      <br />Safety & security
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Budget Preferences</p>
      4000 to 5000 USD per person
      <br />5000 to 6000 USD per person
      <br />Above 6000 USD per person
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to make a hash from it, which would be like this:

```
{
  "Important Preferences" => "To see as much as possible, Relaxation, Quality of accommodation, Quality of activities, Independence & flexibility, Safety & security",
  "Budget Preferences" => "4000 to 5000 USD per person, 5000 to 6000 USD per person, Above 6000 USD per person"
}
```

I tried:

```
params = {}
Nokogiri::HTML("my HTML pls see above").css("td p").each do |item|
  params.merge!({item.text => item.next.text})
end
```

But I couldn't collect values inside `<BR>`.

My result was:

```
{
  "Important Preferences" => "To see as much as possible",
  "Budget Preferences" => "4000 to 5000 USD per person"
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your implementation for others to help debug the issue you are facing?

Comment: You can't get anything from inside `<br>` because `<br>` tags don't wrap anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first step find out all `<td>` tags with `xpath('//td')`. Then, for each, iterate on its children and collect its content, if the child it `Nokogiri::XML::Text` (you don't want to collect `<br>` tags):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
h = {}
doc.xpath('//td').each do |td|
  p = td.at_xpath('p')
  a = []
  td.children.each do |child|
    if Nokogiri::XML::Text === child
      t = child.text.strip
      a << t unless t.empty?
    end
  end
  h[p.text] = a.join(', ')
end
```

result:

```
{"Important Preferences"=>"To see as much as possible, Relaxation, Quality of accommodation, Quality of activities, Independence & flexibility, Safety & security", 
 "Budget Preferences"=>"4000 to 5000 USD per person, 5000 to 6000 USD per person, Above 6000 USD per person"}
```

or in more compressed form, without using the strict loops:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
h = {}
doc.xpath('//td').each do |td|
  h[td.at_xpath('p').text] = td.children
    .select{|x| Nokogiri::XML::Text === x && !x.text.strip.empty?}
    .map{|x| x.text.strip}.join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to get all siblings of `td p`

You can get list of all siblings and remove `p`.

```
item.parent.children.to_a - [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Important Preferences</p>
      To see as much as possible
      <br />Relaxation
      <br />Quality of accommodation
      <br />Quality of activities
      <br />Independence & flexibility
      <br />Safety & security
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Budget Preferences</p>
      4000 to 5000 USD per person
      <br />5000 to 6000 USD per person
      <br />Above 6000 USD per person
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOT

doc.search('td').map { |td|
  key = td.at('p').text
  [
    key,
    td.text.sub(/#{key}/, '').lstrip.gsub(/\n +/, ', ')
  ]
}.to_h 
# => {"Important Preferences"=>"To see as much as possible, Relaxation, Quality of accommodation, Quality of activities, Independence & flexibility, Safety & security, ", "Budget Preferences"=>"4000 to 5000 USD per person, 5000 to 6000 USD per person, Above 6000 USD per person, "}
```

If you're on an older version of Ruby that doesn't have `to_h`, use:

```
Hash[
  doc.search('td').map { |td|
    key = td.at('p').text
    [
      key,
      td.text.sub(/#{key}/, '').lstrip.gsub(/\n +/, ', ')
    ]
  }
]
# => {"Important Preferences"=>"To see as much as possible, Relaxation, Quality of accommodation, Quality of activities, Independence & flexibility, Safety & security, ", "Budget Preferences"=>"4000 to 5000 USD per person, 5000 to 6000 USD per person, Above 6000 USD per person, "}
```